# Universal quantification and the number of solutions

Tags: logic, counting

How would one count the amount of solutions to quantified formulas that have universal quantifiers? For example, for a boolean formula $\Phi(X)$ with a number of solutions $\#\Phi(X)$ let's construct a quantified boolean formula $\forall y \ \exists X: y \lor \Phi(X)$. In this case $X$ represents $n$ boolean variables. What would be the number of solutions to it? Either $0$ or $1$? If so, can we conlude $\mathsf{NP}\in\oplus \mathsf P$?

Or would it be a real number with a number of solutions between $0$ and $1$, like $\frac{\#\Phi(X)}{2^{n+1}}$?

Comment: What counts as a "solution" to such a formula?  Do you really want to ask about only that specific formula?  That formula is equivalent to $\exists X : \Phi(X)$.  Why do you think the number of solutions is either 0 or 1?  Why do you think you would be able to conclude that?

Comment: You know that the decision problem for total quantified boolean formulas, TQBF, is PSPACE-complete, correct? It's very well known that $\mathrm{NP} \subseteq \mathrm{PSPACE}$.

Comment: @Pseudonym, yes, but it also is unclear what would be the number of solutions for TQBF.

Comment: @D.W. These formulas indeed are equivalent, but with a $\forall y$ part it seems that you can't easily count the solutions for $y=0$ and $y=1$ and simply add them together. Of course, besides this example there is a question on how one would count solutions to TQBF, e.g. what would be $PPSPACE$.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  What do you mean by a solution, and what do you mean by the number of solutions?  Please define your terms.  Why do you think you can't count the number of solutions for $y=0$ and $y=1$ and add them?  There is so much about this question that is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be many misconceptions and confusions built into this question, so let me try to help you think about these topics more carefully.  I encourage you to read about fundamental materials on these topics before asking another question in this line, so that you're able to formula your question using standard terminology and are able to clearly express what you're trying to ask.

First, please familiarize yourself with the definition of a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) and [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).  If $\Phi(X)$ is a formula with free variables $X$, then an [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) maps each [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_variable) in $X$ to true or false.  We can then check whether $\Phi(X)$ evaluates to true or false under this assignment.  A satisfying assignment is an assignment for $X$ where $\Phi(X)$ evaluates to true.  Please read each of those links and familiarize yourself with this basic terminology.

Note that we normally only talk about satisfying assignments for formulas with free variables.  It is not terribly useful to talk about satisfying assignments for a formula like $\exists X > \Phi(X)$ or $\forall y \exists X : \Psi(X,y)$, as those have no free variables.  More pedantically, if $\zeta$ is a formula with no free variables, then there is only a single assignment (since there are no free variables, there is only one way to map every free variable to true or false), and it is a satisfying assignment if $\zeta$ evaluates to true and otherwise is not a satisfying assignment.

So, with that foundation, we can then try to interpret your question in a sensible way in one of multiple different ways:

- Perhaps you mean to ask: given a formula $\Phi(X)$ with free variables, count how many satisfying assignments to $X$ it has.  If $\Phi$ has no quantifiers, this is exactly the [#SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-SAT).  #SAT is #P-complete.  If it has quantifiers, the problem might be very hard (I don't know exactly how hard).
- Or perhaps you mean to ask: given a formula $\zeta$ with no free variables, count how many satisfying assignments it has.  The answer to this question will be either 0 or 1: it is 0 if $\zeta$ evaluates to false, or 1 if $\zeta$ evaluates to true.  If $\zeta$ is a Boolean formula with quantifiers, then determining whether $\zeta$ evaluates to true is the [TQBF problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula).  TQBF is PSPACE-complete.
- Or perhaps you mean to ask: given a formula $\Phi(X)$ with free variables $X$ and no quantifiers, count the number of satisfying assignments of $\forall y . \exists X . y \lor \Phi(X)$ specifically.  This is an instance of TQBF, but it is easier than general TQBF.  Note that $\forall y . \exists X . y \lor \Phi(X)$ is a formula with no free variables, so the number of satisfying assignments will be 0 or 1, according to whether it evaluates to true or not.  Moreover this formula evaluates to true iff $\exists X . \Phi(X)$ does.  So, if $\Phi(X)$ is in CNF form (or is any Boolean formula with no quantifiers), this can be tested with a SAT solver.  Thus, this problem is NP-complete.

I don't know where you got $NP \in \oplus P$ from or why you think that has any relationship to this matter.  It's actually not a well-formed statement: both $NP$ and $\oplus P$ are classes of problems, so we can't have $NP \in \oplus P$.  At best you could ask whether $NP \subseteq \oplus P$, but that doesn't appear to have any relationship to the rest of your question.  Please learn about [the $\oplus P$ complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P) as I suspect you may have some misunderstandings about it.